# Update the user's link with either PHP or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, hyperlink

So i was wondering if it would be possible to change the client's link in the browser's searhbar with the help of either PHP or JavaScript(Not jQuery).

So let's say that i have this site with just one normal page but with multiple additional content files for specific subjects.

And these files are fetched with the help of variables stored in the link, just like youtube's: youtube.com/watch?v=105cdU..

And when you click on a link leading to some other content on this site it uses an javaScript ajax to fetch that other content without updating the navigation bar, the footer etc..

Now this all works up until now, but here comes the problem. Whenever an ajax is used, the page won't have the link to just that specific content.

Let's say the site have loaded some content about stawberries and then i'm clicking on a link that uses an ajax to update the content to chocolate instead. Now i'll be reading the content about chocolate but my link will still be directed to the strawberries.

Note that this isn't a real site because I haven't made it yet. So please don't ask for the code. I also appologize for my poor grammar and spelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is correct.

Check Mozilla documentation to find complete details with example

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: Thanks alot! This is definately what I need!

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is called pushState. Here is a Javascript example of using it.

```
if (history.pushState) {
    var newurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + 'VARIABLES I WANT TO ADD';
    window.history.pushState({path:newurl},'',newurl);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! But this site:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState
Says that the basics are supported in every major browser, which I hope are enough for this.

Comment: No problem for the example, hope it helps!